# Puppet could not retrieve information from plugin source

Tags: puppet

Every time I run puppet, I get this error.

> `err: /File[/var/lib/puppet/lib]: Failed to retrieve current state of resource: Could not retrieve information from source(s) puppet://puppet/plugins`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reason this error comes up is you have pluginsync enabled, and you don't have any plugins to sync.  pluginsync is enabled by default in the Ubuntu packages. Unfortunately, due to the design of puppet, the error message is a bit imposing, and throws up some pink in your otherwise green --test output.

There are two options:

1. Disable pluginsync on every client: edit /etc/puppet/puppet.conf and set `pluginsync=false`.
2. Create at least one plugin.

The easiest workaround is to create a single `lib` directory under a module of your choosing. Even an empty plugin is enough to cause the error to go away.

(Answer found in [this bug report](http://projects.reductivelabs.com/issues/2244).)

Answer (score 0):

Check the log file on the server if there any clues, but most likely it's caused by a misconfigured fileserver.conf for puppetmaster.

Comment: Thanks, but I actually posted the question in order to more widely publicise the correct answer. :)